# How to set namespace aware to false?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to parse some XML with EclipseLink MOXy, and it's failing on the line with the `xsi` attribute. If I remove this, it parses fine. However, I've got 100GiB of XML to wade through and changing the source files is not an option.

It's been suggested that if I can set `XmlParser.setNamespaceAware(false)` then it should work - but I've got no idea how to configure this, without breaking right into the guts of MOXy.

```
<record>
<header>
    <!-- citation-id: 14404534; type: journal_article; -->
    <identifier>info:doi/10.1007/s10973-004-0435-2</identifier>
    <datestamp>2009-04-28</datestamp>
    <setSpec>J</setSpec>
    <setSpec>J:1007</setSpec>
    <setSpec>J:1007:2777</setSpec>
</header>
<metadata>
    <crossref xmlns="http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.0 http://www.crossref.org/schema/unixref1.0.xsd">
        <journal>
            <journal_metadata language="en">
[...]
```

The exception I get when the `xsi:` prefix is present is:

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,107]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?crossref&xsi:schemaLocation&xsi]
```

Comment: What is the original problem you are hitting?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan updated. Really hope you can help :)

Comment: In your use case are you able to add the necessary `xmlns:xsi` declaration?  Just checking before we dive into alternate options.

Comment: I can't change the XML in any way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There currently isn't an option in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to tell it to ignore namespaces.  But there is an approach you can use by leveraging a StAX parser.

**Demo**

You can create a StAX `XMLStreamReader` on the XML input that is not namespace aware and then have MOXy unmarshal from that.

```
package forum13416681;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum13416681/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Foo root = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
package forum13416681;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Input (input.xml)**

Below is a simplified version of the XML from your question.  Note that this XML is not properly namespace qualified since it is missing the namespace declaration for the xsi prefix.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.0 http://www.crossref.org/schema/unixref1.0.xsd">
    <bar>Hello World</bar>
</foo>
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>Hello World</bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than disabling namespace awareness altogether, you may be able to use a StAX-implementation-specific mechanism to declare the `xsi` prefix in advance, then parse with namespaces enabled.  For example, with [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org) you can say:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example");

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        ((BasicStreamReader)xsr).getInputElementStack().addNsBinding(
               "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

and then create the unmarshaller and unmarshal the `xsr` as in [Blaise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418763/592139).  While this obviously ties you to one specific StAX implementation, it means that you don't have to modify your existing JAXB model classes if they expect the `<crossref>` element and its children to be in the `http://www.crossref.org/xschema/1.0` namespace.